# Raspberry Pi kernel configuration for USB mouse and keyboard

Tags: kernel, cross-compilation, arm

I've been trying cross compile kernel using this guide.

http://elinux.org/Rpi_kernel_compilation#2._Cross_compiling_from_Linux.

However, all my kernel doesn't support USB mouse and keyboard. In the menuconfig section, what driver/module I need to activate in order my kernel to support USB mouse and keyboard?

Comment: what prevents you from using precompiled raspbian/arch/whatever images? these support mouse and keyboard just fine.

Comment: It is an assignment of mine to compile our kernel, unfortunately.

Comment: can you choose another kernel? it's much easier to build the kernel under, for example, ubuntu on the contemporary PC without any cross compiling hassle.

Answer (score 3):

To enable USB mouse/keyboard support in the kernel, run `make menuconfig`. Go to `Device Drivers` -> `HID support` -> `USB HID support` and select `USB HID transport layer`, which is `CONFIG_USB_HID`. I'm not sure it's necessary for the terminal, but you may also want to enable `Event interface` (`CONFIG_INPUT_EVDEV`) under `Input device support` if it isn't already in order to be able to use the mouse and keyboard under Xorg.

Answer (score 2):

You can often find the configurations used to compile the currently running kernel in the special file `/proc/config.gz` . You could use this configuration as a starting point when compiling your own kernel. Get it from the Pi, gunzip it, and tell `make menuconfig` to load this configuration (can't remember exactly how).

The configuration is actually stored within the kernel itself. This can be turned off when the kernel is compiled, but my current kernels for both Arch Linux and Raspbian have it. And indeed, the [instructions](http://elinux.org/Raspberry_Pi_Kernel_Compilation#Perform_the_compilation) include this step, a bit further down.

Answer (score 1):

you should beable to find what you need to do here:
http://elinux.org/RPi_Kernel_Compilation#Get_the_kernel_source